# AWS API Gateway - HTTP Proxy for all Methods of a resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Is there a way to configure the HTTP Proxy for all methods of resource at once so

**FIRST:**

GET,POST,PUT,DELETE of /v1/resource should all be forwarded to http://api.com/resource/{id}

**If that is possible can I still map:**

GET /v1/resource/schema to an S3 ?

or do i have to define them one by one.

The emergency way to save some time is probably to generate a swagger API documentation and create the API Gateway setup of it.

Answer (score 2):

API Gateway doesn't support to set up multiple methods for one resource at once. As you already mentioned, you could create a Swagger template and use the API Gateway Importer tool (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-importer).

Best,

Jurgen